# figure out mysql ini settings via command line

Tags: mysql

For php there is `php -i`. For apache i can debug settings with `apachectl -S`.

Is there a way for me to output via command line what the current "sourced" settings for mysql are?

I'm trying to figure out if i correctly set my innodb poolsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query it from the command line with an account that has enough privileges.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "show variables;"
mysql -u root -p -e "show variables like '%innodb%';"
mysql -u root -p -e "show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be pleased with either of these commands:

mysqld --verbose --help
or
mysqladmin variables